# issue with select option as input i

Tags: php, html

Gurus,

I wrote code for more than 30 field in a php form with text as input.
some field can be as simple as yes/no as input which I tried to make them as select drop down, eventually I got the code for dropdown by those are not in populating into the table as the text fields.

here is the code sample.

### working text one is

```
<tr>
    <td style="color:black;background-color:WhiteSmoke;" class="auto-style3">Model</td>
    <td class="auto-style4">
    <input id="Text2" type="text" name='model'/></td>
</tr>
```

Problematic code is below

```
<tr>
    <td style="color:black;background-color:WhiteSmoke;" class="auto-style3">Is Virtual Name?</td>
    <td class="auto-style4">
        <select name="isvirtualname">
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
        </select>
       <input id="Text1" type="select" name='Is Virtual Name' /></td>
    </td>
</tr>
```

new code also not

```
            <td style="color:black;background-color:WhiteSmoke;" class="auto-style3">Is Virtual Name?</td>

            <td class="auto-style4">
<select name="IsVirtualName">
<option value="">---Please shoose an option--
</option>
<option value="Yes">Yes</option>
<option value="No">No</option>
</select>


    </td>

        </tr>
```

Comment: Populating where?

Comment: It's not really clear what your problem is. Please take a minute to read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Would you please show relevant back-end code?

Comment: Sure, with the help of a form I am inserting data into a MSSQL table. if I use text fields as input it get inserted in to the database without issues. to simplify user experience I though of adding dropdown options.  the page is getting loaded with the dropdown list for the scripted fields.  but when I submit the form these drop down selected fields are not inserted into the database. I think I am failing to write the proper input code for the drop down fields. Hope this give you some detail information. thanks for your time

Comment: Lol, what is the input with type "select" (*<input id="Text1" type="select"*)?

Comment: as mentioned in my code the input with type select. am I wrong in explaining the problem

Comment: issue persists, can anyone please help me

Answer (score 0):

`type="select"` is not a valid attribute. See [this article on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#Form_%3Cinput%3E_types) for the valid attributes. You either use `<input>` or `<select>` but not both. If you want a normal input box with predefined values you could also take a look at the `<datalist>` element.

Comment: I created the select option and going fine till page and again I am not seeing the values in the database